# How does the Google Place API request query work with multiple types?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have a problem with the google query. I want to search for, let's say nearby dentist cabinets. Almost all cabinets have among types the "health" type, but there are a few that have just "establishment" as type. I want as **results all the dentist cabinets that have among types "health" or "establishment"** so I did as following:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.805361,2.127163&radius=5000&types=health|establishment&key=***
```

and it **returns some results** that have **"health" OR "establishment"** as type(not always both). For example it returns 4 results that have the "health" type.

BUT(here comes the confusion): **If I query only after "health" (&types=health&)** **without establishment** I get **more results with the type "health"**. NOTE: As I read through the documentation the **pipe** |  between types **act as OR and not as AND** so I must get all the results that have "health" OR "establishment" as a type but I don't get all of them. WHY?

Can someone help me with my confusion/issue? How does the query work with multiple types?

Thank you! Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of returned results is limited to **20**, you'll never get "all" results for any query(except there are less than 21 matching places at all)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but in cases where you have more than 20 results, google returns a pagination object which can be used to fetch the additional results. We will have to handle the storing of the previous set of results. Here is the link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceSearchPagination